# Use ExtJS DateField in CF query

Tags: extjs, coldfusion, datepicker

I am using an Ext DateField like this in **date.js** ( I only have access to Ext 2.2 here and CF    7,0,2,142559 on JRun4):

```
function initCalendars() {
var textFields = Ext.query('.ExtDateField');
var dateFields = [];
Ext.each(textFields, function(textField) {
    var dateField = new Ext.form.DateField({
        allowBlank:false,
        format:'Y-m-d',
        applyTo: textField
    });
    dateFields.push(dateField)
});
}

Ext.onReady(initCalendars, this);
```

I found this simple solution on line but now I need to get the date to my CF query from **order.cfm**...

```
<form id="commForm">
<label for="date1">Pick a Date... </label>
<input class="ExtDateField" type='text' name='date1' value=""/>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Search">
<br>
<br>

</form>



<cfinvoke 
    component="MyComponent" 
    method="getMethod"  
    returnvariable="commlist">
        <cfinvokeargument name="order_dt" value="?????????">
</cfinvoke>
```

I am stuck as to what to use for value to send this to the query.  I tried #date1.getValue#, #commForm.date1.getValue# and "commForm.date1.getValue" and get CF errors telling me that either order_dt is not a date type or that date1 is undefined.  Probably something basic but I can't figure it out.

The .cfc works fine when I enter a date manually and I'd really like to get the date picker working if I can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nevermind...I am addlebrained.   I would delete this but maybe someone can benefit from my mistake.  I needed to use the URL scope....

```
#url.date1#
```

worked just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean the form scope (not the url)?  #form.date1#  From your example code it would appear that the value is being passed in the form scope.

By the way, please don't use the form or url scope variables directly in your code like that.  It will open you up for attacks.  Sanitize the values before you use them.